# Using lapply in Spotfire

Tags: r, spotfire

I am trying to introduce the (list apply) lapply function into Spotfire. How would you go about doing that? And is lapply recognized as a function in Spotfire or should i basically create the function from scratch?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's supported by [`TERR`](https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-enterprise-runtime-for-r), the engine that will run your `R` code. `TIBCO Spotfire` has nothing to do with it.

You need to dig deep into [`Data Functions`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VORaNJg0kzw), and understand how to integrate your `R` code, as this is very platform depended based on what `Spotfire` is being used for.

Suggestion would be to use [`Rstudio`](https://www.rstudio.com/) and develop your data function (code) offline, before moving to `Spotfire`. You can download and configure [`TERR`](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/4.1.1/doc/html/TIB_terr_Using-TERR-with-RStudio/GUID-D862005C-0E50-4DD2-94C8-CFEE6F555666.html) to test your code with `Rstudio`.

Comment: As well as https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.3/doc/html/df/df_details_on_register_data_functions.htm

Comment: Thank you for your help Chetan (the edit was not needed however). The only problem is that "TERR" does not seem to be running in my R console.     "package 'TERR' is not available (for R version 3.4.0)".

Comment: @KarimKardous - Which `R` console are you using? `TERR` is not package, it's an engine like `R` open source. Please give more details.

Comment: I am using RStudio 3.4.0. I would like the below function to run using TERR. How do I go about doing that?                                                                                                                                      
    lapply_v2 <- function(x, f, ...) {
    out <- vector("list", length(x))
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
      out[[i]] <- f(x[[i]], ...)
    }
    out
  }

Comment: @KarimKardous - In my answer, I did add a link regarding this. Check [this document from TIBCO](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/4.2.0/doc/html/TIB_terr_Using-TERR-with-RStudio/GUID-DAA6F26E-1CF1-4697-9B38-56A638468C26.html) on how to change `R` open source to `TERR`. With that your code will be compiled using `TERR` not `R`.

Comment: Ok I will try that. Thank you Chetan!

Comment: @KarimKardous - The question you asked was not about the code. I suggest, you ask a new question which is specifically about your `R` code, what data set you are using, and what `error` you get. This has nothing to do with `TERR`, as both `R` open source and `TERR` is used to compile the `R` code.

Comment: The code works. I would like to register that code in Spotfire as a data function so that other users can use this. I am also not allowed to move the installation path of R to that of TIBCO because I am using a company computer. My question is do you know how to take that code and register it as a data function in Spotfire?

Comment: @KarimKardous - Check the first comment by scsimon, which has the [link](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.3/doc/html/df/df_details_on_register_data_functions.htm) on how to do what you want to achieve. You basically write `R` code as `Data Function` using `Tools -> Register Data Function` and then use it from `Insert -> Data Function`.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. I was away from my desktop. Thanks again for your help Chetan!

Comment: @KarimKardous - You should [avoid thank you note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment) in comments. Instead, accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: .@KarimKardous - Why haven't you accepted my answer if it helped you with what you asked for?